# $(0,1)$ without union of intervals centered at rational numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of all rational numbers in $(0,1)$ and let
$$\mathscr{I}_t:=\bigcup_i\left(a_i-\frac{t}{2^{i+1}},a_i+\frac{t}{2^{i+1}}\right)\bigcap\,(0,1)\text{.}$$
Then $\lambda(\mathscr{I}_t)\leq t$ because $\displaystyle\sum_n\frac{t}{2^n}=t$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. That means $\mathscr{I}_t\subsetneq(0,1)$ for $t<1$.

I'm trying to understand what $(0,1)\setminus\mathscr{I}_t$ looks like and in which way it depends on the enumeration of the rationals.

My thoughts: Obviously it would only contain irrational numbers. Any $x\in(0,1)\setminus\mathscr{I}_t$ has to satisfy $\mid x-a_i\mid\geq\frac{t}{2^{i+1}}\forall i$. But I'm trying to build an intuitive understanding and don't know how such an $x$ would look like.

Answer (score 0):

What is your exact question? I'm assuming you already know the Cantor set but if not maybe that's a place to start. It's not quite the same, as the Cantor set still contains rational numbers.

It might also help to start with the "simple" enumeration 1/2, 1/3, 2/3, 1/4, 3/4, 1/5...

One thing that is interesting to notice is that your set can have a measure arbitrarily close to one but never exactly one. One can go even further and prove that any closed subset of the irrational numbers on the unit interval can't have measure 1(when using the Lebesgue measure), due to the fact, that open sets that aren't the empty set have measure greater 0.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion. I'm asking how I can build a more intuitive understanding of how $(0,1)\setminus\mathscr{I}_t$ looks like. I also think starting with the simple enumeration is a good idea but I think even then the structure of the set isn't easy to understand (atleast for me). You can also show that $\lambda(\mathscr{I}_t)$ can take any value between $0$ and $1$ for a suitable value of $t$.

Comment: Do you need it for a homework exercise or some type of research or are you just curious?

Comment: I used the set to solve my homework and wanted to understand it better